# Как загрузить массив значений в IN() mysql

Tags: mysql, pdo

Имеется вот такой кусок кода:

```
$crDetails = '"'.implode('","', $craftDetails['rar_2']).'"';
$sql = 'SELECT id FROM items WHERE rarity = "Необычный" AND title IN (:crDetails)';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([':crDetails' => $crDetails]);
$stmt = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

$craftDetails имеет следующий вид:

```
$craftDetails = [
  'rar_2' => [
       'Строка0',
       'Строка1',
       'Строка2',
       'Строка3'
   ],
 ]
```

В данном случае я пытаюсь соединить все строки ключа 'rar_2', чтобы искать по ним нужные строки с полем title, соответствующим значениям: "Строка0", "Строка1", "Строка2", "Строка3".
Но mysql выдает пустой массив(видимо считает все значение за title). Как решить в данном случае проблему?

P.S. - $crDetails в итоге выглядит так: "Строка0","Строка1","Строка2","Строка3".

Передавать значения напрямую без подготовленного выражения не хочется, хоть данные и не пользовательские .

Comment: Обычно для in генерят строку (?,?,?,?,...) с количеством вопросов соответствующим количество элементов в массиве и в execute передают сам массив, что бы он каждое отдельное значение из него привязал

Comment: Благодарю за информацию)